# Automatically verify email with google sign in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have implemented email password sign up using firebase auth successfully in which I have implemented the email verification as well. Now whenever the user logs in email verification is checked and then only user proceeds ahead.

Now I have implemented google sign in/ sign up. In which I have not implemented email verification to reduce the hassles for the user. But as I told above the whenever the user logs in the email verification is checked only then the user proceeds ahead.

All I want is that if user signs up with google sign in , the email should be automatically verified, rather than user to open his account to verify the account.

How is it possible to implement the email verification in google sign up?

I have implemented this in android using firebase auth.

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Comment: @Rajni Tandon, Have you got any answers? I have implemented security rules that allow requests only if the email is verified. In my case, the email must have to be verified. I can't do it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of authentication which Firebase Auth provides:

1. Email Signup (Which send some verification mail)
2. Google sign-in

So I think what you can do is, whenever Google sign-in is done, you can consider it as a registered user, hence you can say that his email is verified.

If any user is doing email signup, then he would have to go through the process of verification email.

`How is it possible to implement the email verification in google sign up?`

I don't think it is possible with Firebase Authentication since it's not meant to work like that.

Comment: Email Sign Up and Verification perfectly working, but when the google sign up is done, email verification should have done automatically by firebase without any provisions like that of email sign up, which is not happening, how should I make sure that google sign up email verification is already done?

Comment: I don't think there is such thing from Firebase side. You need to store it in your DB about such thing (if you have any DB)

Comment: thanks, then i would avoid to implement google sign up till this resolution comes up

Answer (score 0):

You can use admin SDK to check if the user signs in from Google then update his `emailVerified` token:

`admin.auth().updateUser(uid, { emailVerified: true })`

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to read the `providerId` from the result received after `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credentials)`. In the case of Google signing the provider id will be `google.com`. Based on this value you can decide whether to check for email verification.
I hope ti still helps.